# Having issues in setting up heroku app?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, redux, react-redux

I have created a web application which uses technology like Node.js and React.js. Now I created it and now I am trying to push this app to Heroku and when I do that it shows some error persistently, I tried in very different numerous ways but it doesn't work. Error log is something like this:

```
Counting objects: 25717, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16046/16046), done.
Writing objects: 100% (25717/25717), 26.05 MiB | 59.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 25717 (delta 8710), reused 25548 (delta 8617)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 12, column 3
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 12, column 3
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 12, column 3
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 12, column 3
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to optioncapital.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/optioncapital.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/optioncapital.git'
```

I am not understanding weather procfile and all are required or not, but I am learning through one online course and that person isn't doing anything like that.... Please tell me how to resolve this issue...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this error:

`remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 12, column 3
remote:  !     Unable to parse package.json`

It looks like you are having an issue with the `package.json`

## ===========================================

#### Do this

Delete 'node_modules' folder

`npm cache clean`

`npm update`